# How to properly evaluate sage code from within a Python script

Tags: python, sage, evaluate

I've been trying to evaluate a simple "integrate(x,x)" statement from within Python, by following the Sage instructions for importing Sage into Python. Here's my entire script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env sage -python

from sage.all import *
def main():
    integrate(x,x)
    pass
main()
```

When I try to run it from the command line, I get this error thrown:

```
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

I've tried adding `var(x)` into the script, `global x`, tried replacing `integrate(x,x)` with `sage.integrate(x,x)`, but I can't seem to get it to work, I always get an error thrown.

The command I'm using is `./sage -python /Applications/path_to/script.py`

I can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Edit: I have a feeling it has something to do with the way I've "imported" sage. I have my a folder, let's call it folder 1, and inside of folder 1 is the "sage" folder and the "script.py"

I am thinking this because typing "sage." doesn't bring up any autocomplete options.

Comment: why is it in  another function main?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this. I tried removing the def main(): and main() lines and that didn't change anything.

Comment: I just thought it was convention to put code in a main() function. I learned Java before Python and code wouldn't run without a main().

Comment: i imagine integrate is a function in it's own right so you can call it directly, the docs don;t show any usage as you have above, I had no issues running their examples.

Comment: So could you please explain the changes in my code I'd need to make?

Comment: I tried running sage.integrate without the main function and got 'AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'integrate''

Comment: have you checked out the example code? Also what parameters is integrate supposed to take?

Comment: on the sagecellserver integrate(x,x) works just fine. and yes I have looked at their example code. I don't see anything different from what I'm doing.

Comment: Putting everything inside a `main` function is not a common convention in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name `x` is not imported by `import sage.all`. To define a variable `x`, you need to issue a `var` statement, like thus

```
var('x')
integrate(x,x)
```

or, better,

```
x = SR.var('x')
integrate(x,x)
```

the second example does not automagically inject the name `x` in the global scope, so that you have to explicitly assign it to a variable.

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct but I am wondering, so there is no way to evaluate normal sage code from within python? because within sage, integrate(x,x) would work without declaring x as a variable

Comment: Normal sage code is not python code. For example, `(1..2)` is valid sage syntax, while it is a syntax error in python. So no, it makes no sense running "normal Sage code" in python.

If you want to execute sage code, why not write it in a `.sage` file?

Comment: Good point, Luca - and I think this might be one of the only things that isn't imported into the global namespace that is in a standard Sage session.  Can you think of any others?

Comment: Can't think of any other, I must admit I was surprised to learn it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what Sage does (see the file `src/sage/all_cmdline.py`):

```
from sage.all import *
from sage.calculus.predefined import x
```

If you put these lines in your Python file, then `integrate(x,x)` will work. (In fact, `sage.calculus.predefined` just defines `x` using the `var` function from `sage.symbolic.ring`; this just calls `SR.var`, as suggested in the other answer. But if you want to really imitate Sage's initialization process, these two lines are what you need.)