# How to import sage into a .py file?

Tags: python, module, sage

I have downloaded sage and the notebook works properly as well as in the terminal, but how do I import it into a .py file?

I've tried

```
from sage.all import *
```

but I just get an output of

```
    from sage.all import *
ImportError: No module named sage.all
```

Do I need to change the path and if so what do I need to move into the file's folder? I'm at a loss and have tried their site, however it did not seem the help much.

Comment: where are you trying to import this?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham into a .py file. From what I've read, one way is use the subprocess module, however I'm having trouble with that too.

Comment: have you added `#!/usr/bin sage -python` to your script?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes and I'm still getting a no module name error. Using the command line, I can navigate to /usr/bin and execute sage -python and it opens the interpreter and imports sage properly, however in my editor, I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: Using `#!/usr/bin sage -python` may not work, since `#!/usr/bin ...` may not work properly with multiple arguments. What happens if you run `sage --python FILE.py`? What happens if you run `sage --sh` first (which makes sure your PATH is set correctly, among other things), and then execute `FILE.py`?

Comment: how are you running the script exactly?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri, why would it not work, that is exactly how you are meant to call it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `#!/usr/bin/env sage -python`. Searching for `"/usr/bin/env arguments"` leads to many pages saying that Linux, for example, will pass the rest of the line as a single argument, and since you probably don't have a file called `"sage -python"`, it won't find anything to run. Have you just tried `#!/usr/bin/env sage`?

Comment: This is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592346/how-to-properly-evaluate-sage-code-from-within-a-python-script as well...